# Linux vs Windows for clojure development

Tags: linux, windows, clojure, leiningen

I am starting to learn Clojure. I have tried it on windows on IntelliJ IDEA 14 with new cursive plugin and Eclipse with counterclockwise plugin. I have a lot of troubles with installing and setting up the leiningen, repl and other plugins/tools useful for Clojure development.

My question is: Is it worth effort and time to switch from Windows to Linux ubuntu or some other distro, because I heard there are so much advantages of Linux terminal and other tools.

PS. Emacs to hard for me to learn yet :)

Comment: What problems are you having with installing `lein`? When I started learning Clojure I was using Win 7, but ran leiningen from [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/install.html) which provides a linux like terminal. Eventually I migrated to linux and it's amazing how everything just works there. On the other hand if you are not actually planning on using it as your main OS then it might get a little awkward switching from one to the other, unless of course you run a linux VM from Win 7.

Comment: I'm a 10th year Ubuntu user myself and happy with it but I suggest you change OS for the right reasons. Clojure developing is plattform independent so you don't need to change your favorite OS.

Comment: @juan.facorro frequently i have problems with commands i write in terminals on Windows. I will try vagrant or cygwin and i hope it will help me. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: about emacs on windows... that motivated me to to switch development full time to something non-windows.  there is too many caveats on windows with non-posix compliant tools such as grep, paths, etc.  Tramp works poorly (if at all), you can't run an emacs daemon well, etc.  Emacs on windows is not as good as emacs on *nix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use Intellij 14 with Cursive on both OSX (at work) and Windows (at home).  The experience is essentially identical within those environments, and you can share your Intellij config between them.  The only difference comes on the command line, where the OSX terminals are way better than the Windows ones (although [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/) helps a lot), so on Windows I also run a headless linux VM with [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) because I prefer a linux-ey shell and have got bored of Cygwin.

I'd say there's no Clojure-specific reason to choose OSX, Windows or Linux over the others.  Make your choice for other reasons that are important to you.

Incidentally I've also tried [LightTable](http://lighttable.com/), and it is an excellent Clojure dev environment, but isn't nearly so useful for polyglot development - I'd recommend Intellij or Emacs ahead of it.  If I'm using Java interop with Clojure or JavaScript interop with ClojureScript, I value the full functionality Intellij provides when I jump through into those languages.  Both Intellij and Emacs have the abilities to run REPLs and send forms to them, and Intellij 14 now has a [Show Variables In Editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/) debugging option, which isn't a million miles away from LightTable's Instarepl.

Comment: If anyone has experience of using Eclipse for Clojure, please feel free to add it here, to round out this answer.

Comment: Having heard this discussed at a few events recently, it seems to be the case that the leading options are Intellij with [Cursive](https://cursive-ide.com/) or Emacs with [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider).  Both are comparable in features, and both outstrip any other option considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell is it worth it. It depends on personal taste, I would say.

Other than switching to Linux, you might want to check out [Light Table](http://lighttable.com/). I also started my Clojure quest with setup problems, once I simplified my environment to just Leiningen and Light Table it all started to fall into place.

Once you get some experience how things work, switching to a more sophisticated env is a possibility.